# Help with Clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, clean-urls

I am very new to php (in fact about 2 days old). After getting ripped off by my last webhost I have decided to move my website to a different host. A friend has been helping me do this as he has a little info but we are now stuck and I have tried finding a soloution on google but most answers are way over my head. My site is a php site with a mysql database. We have moved the database and ftp'd the site and everything is now working on the new server except one thing - my site was designed originally to use clean urls? When I go to my shop page (ie: mywebsite.com and click on the shop link - mywebsite.com/shop/ (shows in the bottom left of my browser) I get a page not found error, yet when I type in the url mywebsite.com/shop.php the page displays fine. In addition, if I go to mywebsite.com/shop/shoes/ (another link which shows the preceding link in the bottom left hand corner) I get a page not found error.  Also if I type in mywebsite.com/shop/shoes.php in the address bar I also get a page not found error even though the page shoes.php exists on the ftp server in a folder called templates - if I go to mywebsite.com/templates/shoes.php it shows up) I understand this is called clean urls and I need to add an .htaccess file to sort out the issue. I have looked on the ftp area of my old host and cannot find this file but have been told it is probably hidden. I have been told by my new provider that mod-rewrite is available on the server but I have no idea how to write this htaccess file. Can anyone please give me a step by step on how to do this as I am not a coder.

Additional Details

I have the following files in my root directory: index.php, shop.php, checkout.php, completed.php, contact.php ... I then have a folder called templates and in this folder I have: shoes.php. clothes.php, coats.php ...

The issue I am having is that most of the php files in my root directory already have href-links? pointing to places like mysite.com/shop/ and mysite.com/shop/shoes/ so when I open up the home page in my browser and hover over the links these are the addresses I see and when I click on the links I get page not found as the borwser must be looking for the links in the wrong place. (these links worked fine however on the last host I used). I understand I need an htaccess file to re-direct these links to the correct places. - ie the link for mysite.com/shop/shoes/ is actually linking to a page called shoes.php located in root/templates. I understand this method was used to tidy up the urls?? ie: instead of having mysite.com/templates/shoes.php the urls shows mysite.com/shop/shoes/. I have looked at the code within some of the php pages in the root and they all have lots of links to these 'false' addresses - ie: mysite.com/shop/shoes/ when the actual file should be at mysite.com/templates/shoes.php. I don't want to go through each file one at a time as they are hundreds of links, thus the reason for trying to make this htaccess file. Thanks for your time, Dave

Answer (score 2):

Try to find an option on your FTP client software to show hidden files.

The name of this file is `.htaccess` (dot htaccess), that is probably the reason you're not seeing it. If the old site is working then the file is probably there. You could also contact somebody to send you the file via e-mail, IM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need mod_rewrite or .htaccess for this.

Turn on [multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) in your Apache configuration. This will allow you to omit the `.php` extension from your URLs.